# Passing PHP variable to JwPlayer

Tags: javascript, php, jwplayer

I'm looping the video URL from database and each video has a certain frame that I would like to "seek" to. I'm using the "seek" function provided from JwPlayer.

However, I can't seem to get it right on how to pass the variable to JwPlayer javascript.
Below is my JS for JwPlayer:

```
$('.video').fancybox({
    content : '<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>',
    fitToView : true,
    afterShow : function() {
        this.content = jwplayer('myElement').setup({            
            flashplayer: "js/jwplayer.flash.swf",
            file: this.href,
            height: 360,
            width: 640,
            autoStart : false,
            stretching : "fill"
        }); 
        // Store references to tag and rates
        var videoTag;
        var currentRate = 1;

        jwplayer().onReady(function() {
            jwplayer().seek(<?=$sec?>);
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my HTML

```
<a class="video fancybox.iframe" href="<?=$video_link;?>">Watch Video</a>
```

Can anyone help to advise how I can put in the "sec" to `jwplayer.seek`? I tried using "id" and then get the ID but it's not working either.

Comment: Depending on what version of PHP you're using and what options you have enabled, you may not be able to use short tags (i.e. `<?=`). Try doing `<?php echo $sec; ?>`. What does it look like if you view the source in your browser?

Comment: I can't put the <?=$sec?> there, it's just an indication the seek variable is there. The JS script is at the header, while the variables such as $video_link and $sec are obtained from a while loop.
I need to pass the $sec to the JS so it can be used in the jwplayer

Comment: Also since the file for the player is a variable, you should set the player's type variable to mp4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you have a number of those `<a>` tags, and you want each of them to indicate a different `$sec` value. If that's the case, you can try this:

```
<a onclick="seek(<?=$sec?>)" class="video fancybox.iframe" href="<?=$video_link?>">Watch Video</a>
```

And have a JS function like this:

```
function seek(sec) {
    jwplayer().onReady(function() {
        jwplayer.seek(sec);
    });
}
```

Or, if you are using HTML5, you can try a data attribute on your `<a>` tag:

```
<a data-sec="<?=sec?>" class="video fancybox.iframe" href="<?=$video_link?>">Watch Video</a>
```

And modify your JS to use it:

```
$('.video').fancybox({
    // ...
    afterShow: function() {
        // ...
        jwplayer().onReady(function() {
            jwplayer().seek($(this).data('sec'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried both method, but for method 1, the jwplayer onReady function will not trigger at all (I tried to put alert in there). So I use the method 2, but the data('sec') is not being passed over. Then I changed it to var linkvideo = document.getElementById('linkvideo'); var sec = linkvideo.getAttribute('sec'); alert(sec);   and jwplayer().seek(sec); but the sec variable is blank. any advise? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, I have managed to solved the issue. I created a new function and pass in the variable, together with the whole $(.video).fancybox() function then it works.
Thank you very much for your help!